# Verifying that a map $f: A \to A$ that is injective is automatically surjective

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove the statement that if $A$ is a finite set, any injective function $f: A \to A$ is surjective. I'm not certain that my attempt works. My strategy is as follows:

1. Rule out the empty function. I'm not certain I need to do this, but this allows me to proceed under the assumption that that $|A| = n \geq 1$.
2. Define a set $S$ of functions $f^k = \underbrace{f \circ f \circ \cdots f}_{\text{$k$ times}}$ for $k \geq 1$.
3. As $A$ is finite, $A^A$ is finite. There are, in fact, exactly $|A|^{|A|}$ such functions. If $A = \{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$, there are $|A|$ choices as to where $f$ sends $a_1$, $|A|$ choices as to where $f$ sends $a_2$, and so forth, there are $|A|^{|A|}$ such functions. As $S \subset A^A$ and $A^A$ is finite, $S$ is finite.
4. As $S$ is finite, the sequence $f, f^2, f^3, f^4, \ldots$ must contain duplicates; otherwise, the sequence contains infinitely many distinct elements, which is a contradiction to the fact that $S$ is finite.
5. There exist $i,j \geq 1$, with $i < j$, such that $f^i = f^j$.
6. If $i = 1$, $f^i = f$ is injective by assumption. If $i > i$, $f^i$ is a composition of injections and therefore injective. Therefore, it admits a left inverse $g$.
7. Composing with $g$ on the left, we get $g \circ f^i = g \circ f^j$. By associativity of composition and the fact that $i < j$, we get
   $$ 
   \mathrm{id}_A = (g \circ f^i) \circ f^{j-i} = \mathrm{id}_A \circ f^{j-i} = f^{j-i}.
   $$
8. If $j - i = 1$, then $f^{j-i} = f = \mathrm{id}_A$, which is certainly surjective, with each element of $a$ acting as its own, unique preimage. If $j - i > 1$, then $j - i - 1 \geq 1$. By associativity of composition, given $a \in A$, we have
   $$
   f(f^{j-i-1} (a)) = a,
   $$
   so $f$ is surjective.

Does this proof work? I'm interested in particular on whether it is fully rigorous and whether any steps are unnecessary. I don't think the empty function causes any of my above steps to be invalid, except the statement that $|A|^{|A|}$ is the number of functions $A \to A$ (since $0^0$ is undefined), but every other step works. I wasn't certain about composing with $g$ on the left and computing $f^{j-i}$, but I believe this works by using associativity and successively cancelling, leaving $j-i$ copies of $f$.

Comment: It looks fine, but there are a lot simpler approaches.  You can just inductively assign each element of $A$ to something,  and at each step your potential choices goes down by 1 due to injectivity.

Comment: There are different ways to define "finite", depending on an author's preferred approach. What def'n of "finite" are you starting from?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I think the only definition I'm familiar with is: $S$ is finite if it is empty or there exists some $n \geq 1$ such that $S$ is in bijective correspondence with $\{1, \ldots, n\}$.

Comment: @Alan It makes sense to me that there are only $|A|!$ injections $A \to A$ because we'd eventually run out of elements, but I'm not fully sure how the induction would work, especially since there is a "cap" at $|A|$.

Comment: Others have responded to your posting.  For what it's worth, I would have chosen proof by contradiction, under the assumption that there exists a positive integer $n$ such that the elements in $S$ can be indexed, $s_1, s_2, \cdots, s_n$.  Suppose there exists an element $s_k$ such that the Map $M$ does not map anything to $s_k$.  Then, the map $M$ is mapping $n$ elements in the domain to at most $(n-1)$ distinct elements in the range.  ...see next comment

Comment: By the pigeonhole principle, there must exist at least one element $s_r$ in the range such that two distinct elements $s_i, s_j$ both map to $s_r$.  This contradicts the assumption that the map $M$ is injective.

Comment: Love this proof since it is essentially the same proof that finite cancellative semigroups are groups (one of my favorite exercises in Abstract algebra)

Comment: I recommend the small jntroductory book Set Theory by Suppes, which might still be available free on-line. A set $S$ is defined to be Tarski-finite iff every non-empty family $F$ of subsets of S has a $\subset$-minimal member $f$, i.e. if $f\supseteq g\in F$ then $g=f.$ (Unlike the family $\{\Bbb N\setminus \{1,...,n\}: n\in\Bbb N\}$ of subsets of $\Bbb N,$ which has no $\subset$-minimal member.) A set is Tarski-finite iff it is bijective to $\{x\in\Bbb N: x<n\}$ for some $n\in \Bbb N.$

Comment: BTW on this site the custom is that $\Bbb N$ is the positive integers (excluding $0$). I don't like it but I conform to it.

Answer (score 1):

The assertions in the proof are correct.

However, are you learning axiomatic set theory?

For example, do you know what a function is, or how formally to construct the composition of two functions, or how to define by recursion the $k^\text{th}$ iteration of a function?

Axiomatic set theory concerns itself with the formal, rigorous, watertight way of enunciating and proving such things. If you choose to explore it further, best of luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I'm not learning axiomatic set theory. I think I do know what a function is formally, which is its graph, $\{(x, f(x)) \mid \forall x, \; \exists ! y \text{ s.t. } f(x) = y\}$. I believe this comes about by an equivalence relation on the domain. I'm not sure what the $k$th iteration of a function is, unless it just amounts to composing a function with itself $k$ times and in some ways combining (possibly intersecting?) these graphs.

Comment: @Cardinality yes I did just mean the $k$-fold self-composition of the function

Comment: @Cardinality The point is, the proof is not fully rigorous. A lot of definitions and justifications are missing. But this is normal if you're learning set theory by a non-axiomatic approach. If it's a priority for you to have fully rigorous proofs, then a course on axiomatic set theory is in order